# css how to depend one div to another one in auto adjusting width

Tags: html, css

I am using Google maps to show on my website, the problem is currently the map has CSS property FIXED while on the left Side I have a form for reservation, the problem I am encountering is, I don't want my map to be 100% also behind the form I want my google map to start beside the form, for that I have created a dummy div to be exact pixel as form and try to float left the form but I don't know why google map is considering 100% width as full page let me share the code so guys better understand,

This is mega div I created

```
div#mapcontainermega {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed !important;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

inside this div there are two div the form div that is exact pixel of the form width

```
div#mapcenterdiv {
    width: 565px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

and then the map div inside which google map is located,

```
div#mapmap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

now the problem is when I try to decrease the width to 40% it start showing along with the form, but then on different screen sizes bigger there is a clear blank space appearing on the right side ? how can I make it responsive so that the clear space doesn't show up ?

[image: refer to this image for better understanding]

Comment: maybe `div#mapmap { width: calc( 100% - 565px);height: 100%;
    float: left;}`

Comment: no need of calc. you can set max-width:px width, and set width:100%; that will work... :) currently where you intend to give 40% width...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the width of the map 100% & dynamically guess the width then use `calc()` function of CSS

```
div#mapmap {
    width: calc(100% - 565px);
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

I would still suggest giving a `%` width to your form rather than `px`, then just split the width between the 2 children divs

Read about it - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: Is it a work around or standard way, I means I never seen this practice, Is there a normal way to do it, just like define ones percentage 25% another one 75 percent works perfectly fine, but in this case I don't know why its leaving white space on the right side ?

Comment: Hahah .. Its ofcourse not a workaround ... you would have not seen much of it but it is well a standard way. Let me update with the [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc). Just because you haven't come across it, you cant really call it workaround :)

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't means that with the word work-around, I apologize, I just wanted to know that when the master div is 100% child one is 25% and child two is 75% so when changing screen sizes it must not have blank space on either side, but with the current scenario even If I convert the the child one which is 565px to 32% and 100% to 68 percent it is leaving blank space at right when screen size changes, there is no padding margin at all.

Comment: No worries at all mate :) Hmm .. I have a feeling its because of the fixed position given on the parent container. May be I can help you write some new CSS for the map section from the start to avoid that behaviour. If you really want it to be done let me know and we can work on it.